# while using "-1" as index number,the element is inserting at last 2nd position. how its happening?

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

Im trying to insert element at last index of array using index value"-1".but its giving wrong output.

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
n.insert(-1,55)
print(n)
output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 55, 6]
```

Comment: why not just use .append(55) which should automatically add the number to the end of the list?

Comment: Duplicate was the first google result for "python insert negative index"

Comment: Short answer: insert inserts BEFORE.